# export processing to dxf with layers

Tags: export, processing, dxf

I am drawing two differnt sets of lines at the same time in processing. Is there a way to export them into different layers in the dxf file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

DXFRaw library source code for example they provide [source](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/ce11c085568a35732ccfe95dcc61d77465dac1d7/java/libraries/dxf/src/processing/dxf/RawDXF.java)

Here is how to use it

```
RawDXF dxf = (RawDXF) createGraphics(width, height, DXF, "output.dxf");
beginRaw(dxf);

//your code here for layer 0
flush(); //very important
//if you leave it out drawings will go into incorrect layers

dxf.setLayer(1);
//your code here for layer 0
flush();

dxf.setLayer(2);
//your code here for layer 2
flush();

endRaw();
```

in their example they don't tell you about the flush() but this is really important to have the correct object drawn in the correct layers.

Hope this helps